# Can live be used as a lexical verb in future tenses when meaning “live conferencing”?

Tags: verbs, will-future

Context: In technology, there is such a thing as a live video broadcast but I cannot seem to construct a sentence where “live” is the main verb. Consider this example. My colleague is going to be at a live video conference/presentation for work and shared a link for me to watch ... as a live stream. So how can I construct this sentence?

> So, you will be live? (As in you will be *live* this afternoon)?

But if we remove the aux-elements `will be`, is it somehow possible to say:

> Will you live this afternoon with your colleague?

Now, “live” is obviously pronounced like in *live event* rather than the live in “I live with my parent”. But somehow we have no problem with will live being pronounced as that in live event in will be + live, but we do when it is acting as a main verb, our minds automatically pronounces it as the live in “I **live** here”.

This is possibly why:

> Will you live this afternoon with your colleague? (video conference)

is only pseudo-acceptable. It makes your head scratch. It doesn’t seem impossible to be constructed by everyday laymen, but it sounds weird and the second meaning of “live” as in to reside or abode just doesn’t seem to work in this context but our mind automatically seems to think it's that verb. My reason for it not being appropriate is that the future/request *will you live* seems to clash with the time reference `this afternoon`, when meaning to reside or abode, but we have no problem with “Will you live with your colleague” both in the sense of the meaning to abode and in the sense of live broadcasting.

Also, what is strange is I can also replace live with video conference such as in:

> Will you video conference with your colleague?

There is also ambiguity with “video conference” is this a verb or a noun?

In the dictionary “video conference” is only a noun which I agree with but you can also add -ing to it and use it as a verb:

> I am video conferenc**ing** my friend.

In this sense, is it then a verbal noun?

Comment: Technically, English lacks future tenses. It has various ways of talking about events that haven’t yet come to pass and which vary according to the speaker's expectation or volition. Sometimes these employ adverbials; other times they involve periphrastic constructions using assorted auxiliary verbs. For example: *I see my doctor in the morning* or *I’m to see my doctor later today*. Some even talk about past events using nearly the same periphrastic constructions as are in other instances used to talk about future ones, such as *He will have seen his doctor last week.*

Answer (score 3):

*Live* /laɪv/ is an adjective, not a verb, regardless of the tense of the sentence where it occurs.

> So, you will be live?

This uses the *be* + adjective construction. You can't omit *be* any more than you can omit it before any other adjective. For example, we say "The moon **is** bright tonight", "The moon will **be** bright tonight", "Will the moon **be** bright tonight?", and we don't say *"The moon will bright tonight" or *"Will the moon bright tonight"?

"video conference" can be used as a verb. The usage might be recent enough to not be recorded in dictionaries. The compound nominal "video conferencing" might be older than the use of "video conference" as a verb, because nouns and adjectives tend to form compounds of this sort more easily than verbs in English.

Comment: Yeah. Here, I think one has used the noun a lot many times to make it a verb. Just like, “you don’t know something, **google** it!”.

Comment: What tests did you do to know its a verb? [ Will you be *going*, / *playing* / learning / eating ? etc. ] and compare it with [ Will you be *okay*, / *fine*? ] what would you classify the present participles as to be - adj or verb? I can think more of a plethora of be + verb-ing constructions, rather than the be + adjective construction.

Comment: @aesking: Verbs aren't used in the plain form after *to be*: We don't say *"Will you be go", *"Will you be play" etc. So it's hard to argue that "live" is a verb in "Will you be live". Participles are difficult to distinguish from adjectives, and some linguists have argued that participles are adjectives (such as [Björn Lundquist who I cite here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/366940/77227), and [Martin Haspelmath who I cite here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/507494/77227)), but CGEL (for example) categorizes participles as verbs instead.

Comment: @herisson good point, but a little tidbit you **can** use the plain simple verb form after *be*: ... *I was **struck** by lightning*. *Struck* is both the the past simple and past partriciple of *strike*.

Comment: @aeskingL: the "plain form" of a verb refers to the form used for the infinitive, imperative, and non-third-person-singular present tense; "struck" is not the plain form ("strike" is).

Comment: @herisson ah, I see... we call that the **base form**, “plain form” sounds rather broad and non-technical but I guess you could also call it that. [Gngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Base+form%2C+plain+form&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CBase%20form%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cplain%20form%3B%2Cc0) also populates “base form” as more common.

Comment: nibble: in [ngram](https://imgur.com/a/kqZN7TJ) for some reason, when there is a capitalised B in Base, it seems to change the result and that's why my initial link showed different results.

Answer (score 0):

> Will you video conference with your colleague?

This is an instance – a modern one – of verbing a noun, denominalization. It's entered the lexicon, whereas "live" as a verb in this sense hasn't. If it were to, it would derive from an adjective part of speech, the state of "being live".

As an alternative, in some contexts people have adopted the phrase "live streaming" or "to livestream". This does carry connotations of performance and broadcasting rather than conversation with the observer, of course. Stream has [13th century roots as a verb](https://www.etymonline.com/word/stream) meaning "to flow copiously", so it's easily re-appropriated in contemporary communications when flowing ongoing data from one party to another.

> In the dictionary “video conference” is only a noun which I agree with but you can also add -ing to it and use it as a verb

In your example, adding "am" + "-ing" is simply altering the declination from 2nd person to 1st person. It doesn't affect the part of speech compared to the first example.