# In the following sentence, how many places with passive voice are there?

Tags: passive-voice

Consider the sentence:

> The matter reported by the news is prohibited by the law.

"is prohibited" is passive voice here, but what about "reported by the news"? Is it passive voice too?

I'm thinking if the phrase "the matter reported by the news" is a shortened version of "The matter, which is reported by the news". The latter is passive voice I suppose.

Comment: You could look at the passive vs adjectival debate here: [verb or adjective in 'the blue page is stapled to the red page'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/159334/verb-or-adjective-in-the-blue-page-is-stapled-to-the-red-page)? and here [-ed endings – adjective or past participle in perfect-tenses passive voice ...](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/507404/ed-endings-adjective-or-past-participle-in-perfect-tenses-passive-voice-and-af).

Comment: You're right. Both are passive constructions; the first one has had _Whiz_-Deletion applied, shortening it as you note. Both passives are giveaways because they use the relatively rare _by_-Agent phrase to mark the active subject. _By_-phrases are uncommon in passives because one of the points of the passive is to avoid specifying the subject. Who cares that this building was erected in 1967 by Acme Construction? The difficult cases don't use _by_, and there you can't tell whether the _be_ is the required auxiliary for the passive construction, or for a predicate adjective. They're identical.